# Сокрытие виртуальной функции базового класса статической функцией в производном классе

Tags: c++, clang, сокрытие-функций

Имеем код:

```
struct B 
{
    virtual void f() {}
};

struct D : B
{
    void f(int) { }
};

int main() { }
```

clang [выдаёт](https://wandbox.org/permlink/scJkD0aaWK0H30cw) для него предупреждение:

> ```
> 'D::f' hides overloaded virtual function [-Woverloaded-virtual]
> ```

Теперь делаем `f(int)` статической в классе `D`:

```
struct B 
{
    virtual void f() {}
};

struct D : B
{
    static void f(int) { }
};

int main() { }
```

Код компилируется без предупреждений. Однако попытка использовать `f()` на объекте класса `D`:

```
int main() 
{ 
    D d; 
    d.f(); 
}
```

приводит к ошибке:

> ```
> too few arguments to function call, expected 1, have 0
> ```

Т.е. `static f(int)` по-прежнему скрывает функцию из `B`. Проблема решается добавлением `using B::f;` в класс `D` и код [компилируется успешно](https://wandbox.org/permlink/7ZwXoPqeuIBHeb21). Но возникает вопрос:

Есть ли какие-то объективные причины не выдавать предупреждение при сокрытии функции `B::f()` статической `D::f(int)`?

Comment: Имхо, дело в том, что сокрытие функции само по себе не ошибка, и компилятор не должен сыпать варнингами каждый раз, когда это происходит. А вот случайное сокрытие виртуальной функции вместо переопределения, из за неправильной сигнатуры, уже похоже на ошибку.

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb вполне разумное предположение, но сейчас уже есть `override` чтобы этого избежать. Ещё в пользу случайного сокрытия мог бы говорить явный `virtual` (его у меня нет в первом примере кода), но если бы сигнатуры совпали, он бы предполагался неявно.

Comment: У gcc есть флаг -Wsuggest-override, вынуждающий использовать override. Может с ним не будет предупреждения?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Насколько я понимаю, это предупреждение нужно для того, чтобы предотвратить ошибки, связанные с сокрытием виртуальной функции, когда требовалось ее переопределение. Например при опечатке:

```
struct chart;
struct Base{
    virtual void* get(char* e);
};

struct Derived: public Base{
    void* get(chart* e); //Ой
};
```

Ключевое слово `override` могло бы решить эту проблему, но до тех пор пока оно необязательное, эта диагностика будет жить и периодически срабатывать.

Что касается `static`. Думаю, разработчики компилятора рассуждали, что раз виртуальные функции статическими быть не могут, то скорее всего программист не планировал ничего переопределять. Соответственно и ошибки, скорее всего, нет.

Comment: Кажется, я где-то видел этот пример с chart

Comment: @alexolut, возможно [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18515300/5371004). Наткнулся пока пытался найти описание всех варнингов, и не смог пройти мимио